# Loop overflow when looping by blocks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a super slow machine that I need to run a couple hundred thousand `countif` statements on, this is currently causing the machine to run out of ram. So what I want to do is loop through the table 500 cells at a time and then paste as values to stop the out of ram error.

My question is how can I do this when the number of lines in the table is not perfectly divisible by 500. There are 21372 lines. What is happening at the moment is VBA is creating 130 odd extra lines.

```
Sub Macro1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim last As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim K As Long
K = 507
last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For I = 7 To last
  
  Range("A6:AL6").Copy
  Range(Cells(I, 1), Cells(K, 38)).Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
  Calculate
  Range(Cells(I, 1), Cells(K, 38)).Value = Range(Cells(I, 1), Cells(K, 38)).Value
  
  K = K + 500
  I = I + 499
    
  Next I

On Error Resume Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
End Sub
```

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to modify the counter variable of a for loop inside of the loop or else you could have weird bugs. Here you should not modify the value of I inside of your for loop. You might want to try another kind of look like a Do until or While loop.

Comment: Also if your goal is simply to countif() on some range may I suggest that you just write a loop in vba that reads the value of each cell one at a time and then increment some counter variable if it matches your criteria. This may avoid the running out of ram problem.

Comment: The 1 line at a time approach takes 25 minutes, which is why I was trying to do it in blocks of 500

Answer (score 0):

The code below will divide the range into blocks of 500 (you can set a different block size) but create a smaller block at the end. Add your own code in place of the line that now prints the range address.

```
Private Sub DivideAndConquer()

    Const BlockSize As Long = 500           ' change to suit
    
    Dim Rng         As Range
    Dim Rl          As Long                 ' last used row number
    Dim Rstart      As Long                 ' first row in Rng
    Dim Rend        As Long                 ' last row in Rng
    
    ' change the column ID to suit (here the last row is found in column A)
    Rl = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Rstart = 6                              ' this is the first row of the first Rng
    Do While Rend < Rl
        Rend = WorksheetFunction.Min(Rstart + BlockSize, Rl)
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(Rstart, 38), Cells(Rend, 38))
        Debug.Print Rng.Address             ' add your COUNTIF or other action here
        Rstart = Rend + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```